# This program is not scanning the string for the first loop iteration in c program

Tags: c, scanf

This program is not scanning the string for the first loop iteration. Basically first iteration of 'for' is not working.....why?

```
void main()
{
          int T;

          printf("Enter T:");
          scanf("%d",&T);

          char a[T][100];
          int i;
          for(i=0;i<T;i++)
          {
               fgets(a[i],sizeof(a[i]),stdin);
               printf("\n%s",a[i]);

          printf("hii");
          }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you understand what `scanf` and `fgets` do. Convince yourself of your understanding by writing a simple program first before you dive into something complex like this.

Comment: `scanf()` is generally **not** suited for getting raw user input.

Comment: Put some `printf`s in your code and find out what's going on... or better yet, use a debugger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` does not consume the newline character. So, on the first iteration, the first character that `fgets` sees is the newline, and exits immediately. You also may have noticed that all the elements were off by one (i.e. the first string you entered is in `a[0]`, the third in `a[1]` etc).

You'll need to insert a call to `getchar` just after `scanf` to get rid of the newline.

Comment: still got some problem...!first character of the input is consumed somewhere